# What is the best approach to build a project for mobile and web version in GWT?

Tags: mobile, gwt, frameworks, subdomain, project

I build project on GWT. One project for web and other project for mobile. It is a best way to do that or something else ? How to load two projects on same domain like Flipkart.com and Stack Overflow.

I know about bootstrap and other responsive framework. Even GWT has its own. Actually problem is my application is too large cannot work with bootstrap because bootstrap do things on single file like home.html contains code for both mobile and web. But I cannot do that because it too heavy for mobile user & unnecessary load of web components for mobile user.

So, I came to this approach to build two projects, one is for web & other one is mobile. Now problem is how can I load two projects on same domain and I cannot go like ‘sub-domain.main-domain.com’ because of every user account has unique url with their choosen username like ‘kushal.abc.com’. So if its open on mobile so it should be like ‘m.kushal.abc.com’ & I don't think its possible?

Comment: You can check by JS script screen resolution size to decide which template to load mobile view or desktop

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to create ClientFactory and its specific implementations

```
ClientFactory
|-- MobileClientFactoryImpl
|-- DesktopClientFactoryImpl
```

And inside each of this implementation class you may initialize views for concrete views like DesktopMainView.

Inside your GWT module you have to define custom module with some JS snippet. More information about defining custom module you will find in Colin answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14676197/929209) and [GWT Deferred Binding tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#directives)